# CSOM sharing by link detection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

Is there a Site (ClientContext.Web) or File property to see if 'Sharing by Link' is enabled? And if enabled for 'Anyone with the link'?

Answer (score 0):

The sharing setting proprety is a site property and can only be retrieved in SharePoint admin center, below is my sample for you.

```
        var siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test";
        var adminUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com";

        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(adminUrl);
        ctx.Credentials = credentials;

        var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
        SiteProperties siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteUrl, true);
        ctx.Load(siteProp);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(siteProp.Url + ": " + siteProp.SharingCapability) ;
```